# Can't get this simple debounce function to work - what am I missing here?

Tags: javascript

Been trying to make this simple debounce work for a little while, there's something I'm missing here:

```js
function debounce(callback, wait) {
  let timeout;
  return (...args) => {
    const context = this;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(() => callback.apply(context, args), wait);
  };
}

function debounceb1() {
  console.log('debounceb1 called')
  debounce(() => {
    console.log('debounce b1 executed?')
  }, 2000)

}

function debounceb2() {
  console.log('debounceb2 called')
  debounce(function() {
    console.log('debounce b2 executed?')
  }, 2000)
}
```

```html
<button onClick="debounceb1()">
button 1
</button>

<button onClick="debounceb2()">
button 2
</button>
```

As you can see on the snippet, the function passed to debounce never gets called, even after the timeout.
What am I missing?

Comment: ` return (...args) => {` is a function. However, since its a function, it is never being called. If you simply remove that and the reference to `...args` it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`debounce()` returns a function but you never call this function. Only when you call this function, `setTimeout()` is executed.